# Struts2 filter json result /custom result

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, struts2

I'm currently working on a solution for sending a json result from struts2 back to the client.

I followed this example:

http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-and-json-example/

it works fine, but the problem is, that struts2 sends too much information back in the result json, because I got some variables, that should not be displayed to the customer.

Is there a way to send my own Json back or filter the results before sending it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude the properties which you don't want JSON plugin to serialize for you like

```
<result type="json">
  <param name="excludeProperties">
    login.password,
    studentList.*\.sin
  </param>
</result>
```

For detail refer to the [JSON plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/json-plugin.html) page